# I want to perform performance testing.code is in encrypted form and few API there is dependency so I execute the script it is not reflect on FE

Tags: encryption, jmeter

How we can deal with request which are decrypted and response is used in next request in Jmeter performance testing

performance testing using Jmeter tool where response of first API is consider as Request for next API and also when run the Jmeter script it should be reflect on FE

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encrypt or decrypt something as a part of the [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) you can use a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) for this.

Unfortunately we cannot provide comprehensive help without having more context like seeing encrypted response, knowing algorithm, etc.

So far I can only suggest getting familiarized with the following materials:

- [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)